# Back Button with the Same Session Var in previous page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button (Back) in destination Page like this :

```
localhost:22211/Departments/Departments.aspx
```

The Back on Click should take me back to the previous page with

```
localhost:22211/School/School.aspx?SId=122
```

How can I use

```
Response.Redirect(" //? ");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer);
```

EDIT: I don't have VS open right now. Could be `Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()`

Comment: But it's taking me to the same page

Comment: Using this makes Departments.aspx go back to Departments.aspx?

Comment: How do you get to Departments.aspx in the first place? Button click? Link click? Javascript? Redirection?

Answer (score 0):

How you are navigating to that destination page?
i.e. Redirect or a postback linkbutton?
You can set the PostbackUrl of the back button like:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   if (PreviousPage != null)
   {
      btnBack.PostBackUrl = PreviousPage.AppRelativeVirtualPath;
   }
}
```

//Note: PreviousPage won't have value if you are doing redirect from your School page.

OR else you will have to store that url into Session and get that on destination page and set the Back url.